# How can I password protect an Excel UserForm but allow it to be reopened without the password?

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I maintain a workbook of macros for my office. This workbook has a UserForm menu that my teammates use to access the macros, but I also included a developer UserForm with controls that let me bypass certain steps (such as entering information, ranges, etc). We use hotkeys to access these UserForms. How can I password protect this developer UserForm so that nobody else accidentally accesses it?

```
Sub macShowDevPanel()

   frmDevPanel.Show

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To password protect this panel, you just need to add some code that checks to see if the user entered the correct password. This is pretty simple using an InputBox and a conditional.

```
Sub macShowDevPanel()
    ' Source: http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/protect-macro.html
    Dim password as String

    Select Case password
        Case Is = False
            ' do nothing
        Case Is = "CTM"
            frmDevPanel.Show
        Case Else
            MsgBox ("Incorrect Password")
    End Select

End Sub
```

Note that doing it as shown above will ask you for the password each time you hit the hotkey to open the UserForm. You can go around that by declaring `password` as a public variable, meaning it'll stay stored as the proper value for as long as the sheet stays open. When you close it and reopen, you'll have to re-enter the password.

```
Public password as String

Sub macShowDevPanel()

    If password <> "CTM" Then
        password = Application.InputBox("Enter the Dev Panel password", "Dev Panel - Password Protected")
    End If

    Select Case password
        Case Is = "CTM"
            frmDevPanel.Show
        Case Else
            MsgBox ("Incorrect Password")
    End Select

End Sub
```